# C++ UTF-8 strings

Tags: c++, string, c++11, utf-8

I am reading 'The C++ programming language' by Bjarne Stroustrup and in section 7.3.2.2 is stated that by printing:

```
u8"the officials vowels in Danish are:a, e, i o, u, \u00E6, \u00F8, \u00E5 and y."
```

you will get:

> the officials vowels in Danish are:a, e, i o, u, æ, ø, å and y.

However, if i try this on my own machine i get this:

> the officials vowels in Danish are:a, e, i o, u, ├Ž, ├Ş, ├ą and y.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Does your shell/ command prompt able to print utf-8 ?

Comment: I don't know.How do i check that ?

Comment: On a Windows machine you're mostly out of luck for doing this easily because Microsoft's runtime does not support UTF-8 locales. See docs of `setlocale`. There are ways to do this and I've answered it before but it's too much for my limited time now (seconds, sorry).

Comment: Thank you a lot. I tried to find your answer but i couldn't. Can you give me the link please?

Comment: Stroustrup here makes a huge assumption that simply isn't true on Windows: that sending UTF-8 bytes to the console will show the proper characters. Windows values backwards compatibility over anything else, and the characters it's showing you are the same ones it would have shown 35 years ago for the same byte sequence. That's far longer than Unicode has existed. They made a half-hearted attempt to support UTF-8 in the console, but it's buggy and not the default so nobody ever uses it. Try the command `chcp 65001` before running your program.

Comment: @MarkRansom In his defense I don't think he does. He writes "printing it **appropriately**" and avoids using `cout` in this case.

Comment: `"\u00E6, \u00F8, \u00E5"` is the character sequence `"æ, ø, å"`. In UTF-8, that sequence is encoded as bytes `C3 A6 2C 20 C3 B8 2C 20 C3 A5`, which is the character sequence `"├Ž, ├Ş, ├ą"` when those bytes are interpreted in [codepage 852](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852) (the DOS OEM codepage for latin-2).

Answer (score 0):

Windows do not for some reason use UTF-8 by default in the console.

Running the `chcp 65001` as suggested should work (65001 is the [code page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx) of UTF-8).

Or programmatically I use:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    if( !SetConsoleOutputCP( CP_UTF8 ) )
        throw "Setting Windows console to UTF-8 codepage failed!";
#endif
```

PS: IIRC I also had problems using `cout` with it (probably due to `locale`). But `printf()` works for me.